# VLC player only using 1/6 cores

Tags: 14.04, graphics, video

I am using VLC player to take a camera feed and stream it to a web server. I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 server in vmware with a GUI installed. The stream works fine but VLC is only using 1/6 cores. The one that it is using is constantly at 100% usage and will jump from core to core. For example, cpu1 will be at 100% and then drop to 10% and then cpu5 will jump to 100% for another 10 seconds. I gave the machine 128M graphics ram in vmware but I'm not sure how to start using that. Any way to split the load between all the cpus?

Answer (score 1):

You can set number of threads in video codec settings. For instance, go to VLC settings and set ffmpeg number of threads to 6. It will automatically use all cpu's.